# Number only validation not working in ionic app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation, event-binding

```
      <input type="tel" (keydown)="numberOnlyValidation($event)">
```

// Function not able to read input number values

// On typing into the input field nothing in showing mainly not able to read the keyboard number values

```
numberOnlyValidation(event: any) {
        console.log(event.target.value)

//pattern 

        const pattern = /[0-9]/;
        const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
       

        if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
            // invalid character, prevent input
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

``
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.charCode` property only exists on the `keypress` event [Keyboard Event (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)

[The specification says to use the KeyboardEvent.key property instead (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Apart from handling delete, your code should work if you change this line to utilize `event.key`

```
const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode); // remove
const inputChar = event.key; // add
```